# PHP Warning:  sprintf(): Too few arguments in...

Tags: opencart, php

Привет, народ. Появилась следующая проблема. В ЦМС Opencart в исполняемом файле выдает ошибку в строках:

```
if ($this->customer->isLogged()) {
        $this->data['text_message'] = sprintf($this->language->get('text_customer'), $this->url->link('account/account', '', 'SSL'), $this->url->link('account/order', '', 'SSL'), $this->url->link('account/download', '', 'SSL'), $this->url->link('information/contact'));
    } else {
        $this->data['text_message'] = sprintf($this->language->get('text_guest'), $this->url->link('information/contact', '','SSL'));
    }
```

Ругается на тело else. Текст ошибки:

> PHP Warning:  sprintf(): Too few arguments in...

Не могу понять, что не так с аргументами функции. Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

в `$this->language->get('text_guest')` должен быть один аргумент `%s`. А их у вас там штуки 2-3. Нужно сократить до 1. И ошибка исчезнет